# DOM does not recognize an "InseartAdjacentHTML"

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom

I am creating an automation with selenium Webdriver. But it does not recognize the .SendKeys() method because of the #shadow-root.

Then I am using javascriptExecutor.executeScript and the only way that I found to insert a text with all the tags which I need was "InsertAdjacentHTML".

until here it is just perfect!!! The text is there exactly as I want, it is in the resolution notes.

The problem comes to the next step, when I click on the btn resolve or save, it will keep asking me to add the resolution notes. although the notes are there, I can see them!

At this point the automation breaks. And then if I manually give just one click upon the resolution notes, and click on btn resolve or save, it will recognize the text and will be able to save it.

My question is: Why the insertAdjacentHTML is not been recognized by the DOM as a text in the first stage. how to fix that?

Should I give a command to refresh or reload the page ??? If I do that, I think I will lost the text! Is there a way to do it?

Please, if you have faced the same problem on your automation, let me know how to fix it.
If you don't use it for automations, but you know how to fix it, let me know too.

Thank you so much!

```
 String eng1 = "return document.querySelector(\"sn-workspace-layout > sn-workspace-main > sn-workspace-content\")" +
                ".shadowRoot.querySelector(\"now-record-form-connected\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"sn-form-internal-workspace-form-layout\")" +
                ".shadowRoot.querySelector(\"now-record-form-blob\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"sn-form-internal-tabs\")" +
                ".shadowRoot.querySelector(\"sn-form-internal-tab-contents\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"now-record-form-section-column-layout\")" +
                ".shadowRoot.querySelector(\"now-record-html-editor\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"iframe\")" +
                ".contentDocument.activeElement.insertAdjacentHTML(\"afterBegin\", \"<p>****************************************************</p>");";

WebElement notes = (WebElement) jsExecutor.executeScript(eng1);
```

Comment: SHOW your code.

Comment: This is the script that I am passing to insert the text, There is another section where I click in the Btn save, but is is not relevant to the case.

Comment: unclear why you would have `.shadowRoot.querySelector` over and over again

Comment: Typo in the title. "InseartAdjacentHTML" should obviously read "insertAdjacentHTML"

P.S. I strongly suggest undef-checking, as it's likely that the object at that point is undefined. Possibly use the '?.' operator instead of the '.' operator too.

P.P.S. You should use triple-ticks to mark your code:
```
    let blockOfCode = "like that";
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: The Object is founded with out problem, don't pay attention to the shadow-root, it is not the problem!!!!!

The problem is: how to reload/ refresh a div or how to make the DOM recognize the text. 

Please read the entire problem, you will understand.